# Firebird summary fields calculate

Tags: firebird, summary

i want to do this :

```
select 
  id, 
  sum(field1) as a,
  sum(field2) as b,
  a - b as result group by id;
```

but firebird showing "Column unknown. a." error at line "a - b as result". How do make this. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Write the `sum()` out in the subtraction too, ie

```sql
select 
  id, 
  sum(field1) as a,
  sum(field2) as b,
  sum(field1) - sum(field2) as result 
group by id;
```

Comment: or "sum(field1 - field2)"

Comment: Thanks nater. That's better ;)

Comment: Or you can use subqueries.

Comment: Mark can you give me examples?

Comment: Select id, a, b, a-b from (select id,  sum(a)  as a, sum(b) as b from tablename group by id)  as source